# FactoryGirl + Shoulda NoMethodError: undefined method `featured='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, shoulda

I have the following test failing

```
2) Dvd when is featured 
   Failure/Error: subject { Factory(:featured) }
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method `featured=' for #<Dvd:0x007f9cdb50e400>
   # ./spec/models/dvd_spec.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
   # ./spec/models/dvd_spec.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The spec file is a follow

```
describe "when is featured" do 
  subject { Factory(:featured) }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:featured) }  
 end
```

And the Factory

```
# This will guess the Dvd class
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :dvd do
    title "DVD Test Title"
  end

  factory :featured, class: Dvd do
    title "DVD Title Featured"
    featured true
  end
end
```

The DVD model is simply

```
class Dvd < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :title, :featured

end
```

This is the schema

```
create_table "dvds", :force => true do |t|
  ...
  t.boolean  "explicit",           :default => false
  t.boolean  "featured",           :default => false
end
```

Any idea what is causing the test to fail?

Comment: What's the schema look like? Are you missing a migration?

Comment: I wonder if there is a name conflict here. What if you change the name of the factory from `featured` to `featured_dvd`  (and change the subject to `Factory(:featured_dvd)`) and see if that works?

Comment: Is the schema of your test database up to date with your development database.  If it's missing a column, that would cause the error you're seeing.  Try a `rake db:test:prepare`.